# How to set up SSL passthrough with multiple domains with HAproxy?

Tags: ssl, server, load-balancing, haproxy

How does one set up HAproxy for multiple domains, to multiple backends while passing through SSL?

Example in diagram for a better explanation:

```
                              backend_domain_a
domain-a.com-.            .-> 123.123.123.123
             |            |
             +-> haproxy -+
             |            |   backend_domain_b
domain-b.com-'            '-> 789.789.789.789
```

**Note** Each backend server will be issueing their own certificate. Hence the need for SSL passthrough.

I have this configuration, but doesn't work for multiple reasons (the key one being the missing port number):

```
frontend www
        bind *:80
        bind *:443
        option tcplog

        acl host_domain_a hdr(host) -i domain-a.com
        acl host_domain_b hdr(host) -i domain-b.com

        use_backend backend_domain_a if host_domain_a
        use_backend backend_domain_b if host_domain_b

backend backend_domain_a
        server web_a 123.123.123.123 check

backend backend_domain_b
        server web_b 789.789.789.789 check
```

In others words, I want Haxproxy to **not** terminate the SSL.

I initially wanted to do this with `Nginx` but apparently it can't act as a non-terminating point while reading the host details (though might be available in future versions with ssl preread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, couldn't find a sound way to complete this task.

I ended up using `nginx` to complete the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

After googling around, found and tested this method and it works. I don't really understand why there is a need of inspect-delay, but it works!!

```
frontend https_frontend
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    bind *:443
    acl tls req.ssl_hello_type 1
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if tls
    
    acl host_www req.ssl_sni -i example.com
    acl host_www req.ssl_sni -i www.example.com
    acl host_wiki req.ssl_sni -i wiki.example.com

    use_backend https_www if host_www
    use_backend https_wiki if host_wiki

backend https_www
    mode tcp
    option tcplog
    option ssl-hello-chk
    server www 192.168.1.10:443
```

Full article here: https://az.id.au/ops/haproxy-http-and-https-multiple-domains-and-backends/